# Why python 3.5 cannot find modules imported in files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, nltk

I am using python 3.5. I already have nltk.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk.tokenize
>>>
```

But when I run a file and the file contain `import nltk.tokenize` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named nltk.tokenize
```

Comment: `from nltk import tokenize`

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed . But why it is working `import nltk.tokenize` in python interpreter but not inside files?

Comment: and when I do as you said, I get this error `No module named nltk`

Comment: Take a look at http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because your program didn't found the nltk library.
First install nltk from cmd using

`pip install nltk`

If it installed successfully then execute your code.

If you again get the same error then their may be chance that you installed two or more different version of python or python environment on your system .

Their may be two Solution for this

1. Uninstall other version of python or python environment(like Anaconda)

Then again install nltk from cmd `pip install nltk` then execute your program

2. Set the path of python 3.5 in the priority(keep in the top) from the environment variable.

Example:-

`C:\Users\Tech-Ninja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\`

```
C:\Users\Tech-Ninja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\
```

You have to set two path one for python Interpreter and another for Script both in top.

[You can see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocbUO.jpg)

Then again install nltk from cmd `pip install nltk` then execute your program

Excepting it will work for you

Comment: Thank you so much, but I use Ubuntu so I am not sure if that will work for me.

Comment: If you installed more than two or more version of python then their is a chance of this error , because those library you are installing is not get install on the environment of required version. I am suggesting you to uninstall the other version of python. then again install the nltk module

Comment: Thank you. I rated up. But I have only python 2.7 and 3.5. Did not install any other versions and I believe both of these versions came with Ubuntu when I downloaded it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It turned out the script runs on python3 but couple of libraries still require python 2. On python2 I did not have nltk.